# Alternative solutions to prevent knee pain while standing

Tags: knee, tendinitis, standing, weight-bearing-activity

I will reach 40 years old soon, I had a tendinitis on my both knees 2 years ago which gives me pain when I am standing (on the bottom and the sides of the knee). I can stand at most 10 minutes but I can walk for a much longer period of time, walking is not much an issue.

I am going to Disney World soon, 2 years ago I had a tripod chair and some tapes under my knees, but I learned that tripod chairs are now restricted (or I probably got lucky last time). So what could be good alternative solution to survive the waiting lines ... besides fast pass. I saw various model of knee braces ranging from 10$ to 40$ each but I am not sure if it's going to work or what should be the criteria to look for.

Thank you for any information.